# Accessing the view for a row in an Android ListActivity with a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listactivity, listadapter

I have a ListActivity that's populated with a SimpleCursorAdapter which pulls the data from a database.  I want to set images on the rows at runtime based on the data in the database.  If the data is a one, I want a filled-in icon, and if it is 0, I want it to be hollow.

In order to do this, I figured it would be easiest to access the layout of each row individually, and change the image, but I can't figure out how to access the individual rows without clicking on them.

I also eventually want the image itself to have a separate click event from the row it's on, but I'll probably ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 100rabh's link did help me construct better searches which helped me answer the question, the answer I needed was that I needed to build my own custom cursorAdapter which I just extended from SimpleCursorAdapter.

The setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) method helped, although I also did a bit of customization on bindImage to handle all of my cases for the various lists I used this for.